Some thoughts about operator T& () and when it would be implicitly called?
As per the document, which says that
operator std::reference_wrapper<T>::operator T& () const noexcept;      (since C++11)  
                                                                        (constexpr since C++20)
T& std::reference_wrapper<T>::get() const noexcept;                     (since C++11)  
                                                                        (constexpr since C++20)

I have seen similar signatures, say std::unique_ptr<T,Deleter>::operator bool(). But for T&() is a little harder for me to fully master it. I know T& is reference to T.But how to make the compiler to using T& operator() other than T operator() is the first question to be answered.
I try to write a simple code to be familiar with it.And after I have tried several times, the code snippet works finally. :) Though the said code snippet works well, it still looks strange to me. I have never written such code before.
Why the signature is T& operator() other than T operator()? I think it just because to modify the value which std::reference_wrapper is pointed to, the return type must be T& other than T.
// C++ program to demonstrate the 
// use of std::reference_wrapper 
#include <iostream>  
#include <functional> 
using namespace std; 

int main () 
{ 
    char a = 'g', b = 'e', c = 'e', d = 'k', e = 's'; 
    
    // creating an array of character "references": 
    reference_wrapper<char> ref[] = {a, b, c, d, e}; 
    for (char& s : ref) 
        cout << s;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    ref[0].get()='b';
    (char&)(ref[1]) = 'o';
    static_cast<char&>(ref[2]) = 'o';

    for (char& s : ref) 
        cout << s; 

    return 0; 
} 

The aforementioned operator is called explicitly in the code above . Is there any condition that the said convertion/operator implicitly invoked?

"creating an array of character "references"..." Technically c++ doesn't allow to have an array/vector of "references". Why are arrays of references illegal?

@user12002570 Why, what're the reasons lie behind?

The reason is that the c++ standard just doesn't allow it which is because references are not objects by themselves. They're only an alias to one. The c++ standard specifically says: There shall be no references to references, no arrays of references, and no pointers to references.

C++ How does an std::reference_wrapper implicitly convert to reference? and   Why doesn't std::reference_wrapper implicitly cast to a reference when calling member function?

It isn't marked explicit so it can be used in implicit conversion as well.

@user12002570 Another way I like to think about references is they are pointers that MUST point to a valid object (and already must do so at initialization)

Maybe Why does reference_wrapper implement operator() in particular? should help too but it doesn't have an answer yet.

@PepijnKramer But that analogy isn't fully correct/correct because pointers are objects by themselves but references are not. Btw OP's question "when it would be implicitly called?" should be solved by this and this

The term "reference" that is used in (for examples) in C# or Java is not the same as a C++ reference.   In C++, think of a reference as being an alias to a variable.  Whereas in C# or Java think of a reference being a pointer (using C++ terminology).  C++'s std::reference_wrapper is a non-owning smart pointer object (not an alias) with a reference interface (hence the T&) which wraps a pointer (hence, it's re-bindable, yet is not allowed to be nullptr).
